# How to show userdata from a mongodb database on a page, edit the data and save again

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I have a site where you can register as user and log in. Now i am trying to make a profile page where you can change your username, email and password.
I can only get the data from the first user from the table of users in database. How to get user that is currently logged in?

Here i create a user and save to db. This works fine:

```
router.post("/users", async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body)
    try {
        await user.save()
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        console.log(user, token)
        res.status(201).redirect("/")
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

Then i log that user in. That also work as intended.

```
router.post("/users/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        console.log(user, token)
        res.cookie('auth_token', token, { maxAge: 21600000 })
        res.redirect("/frontpage")
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(`<div style="background-color: red; text-align: center"><h1> Wrong credentials - Did you register...?</h1> <a href='/'><h2 style="color: black"> Try again please </h2></a> <a href='/register'><h2 style="color: black"> Register </h2></a><p> ${e} </p></div>`)
    }
})
```

Then i try to get the data using this route and AJAX. Obviously this only get gets the first entry in the database. I tried different things with findById, but coudnt retrieve any data. What am i doing wrong?

```
router.get("/users/me", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne()

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).send()
        }
            console.log(user.id, user.name, user.email)
            res.send(user)
        } catch (e) {
            res.status(500).send()
    }
```

AJAX call:

```
(async function getProfile() {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/users/me",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (user) {
            $("#addData")
                .append($("<tr>"))
                .append($("<input>").val(user.name))
                .append($("<tr>"))
                .append($("<input>").val(user.email))
                .append($("<tr>"))
                .append($("<input>").val(user.password))
                ;
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

It looks like this
[image: It looks like this:]

And here is thehtml:

```
<div class="centered">
        <h2>Profile page</h2>
        <form action="/users/me" method="GET">

            <table id="profile">
                <thead></thead>
                <tbody id="addData">

                </tbody>

            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update account</button>
            <a href="/login"><button class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-profile" onclick="deleteUser()">Delete
                    account</button></a>
        </form>
```

Then i want to be able to edit name and email and save it again. Here is the post route:

```
router.post("/users/me", async (req, res) => {
    const updates = Object.keys(req.body)
    console.log("Updates1" + updates)
    const allowedUpdates = ["name", "email", "password", "age"]
    const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update))

    if (!isValidOperation) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: "Invalid updates!" })
    }

    try {
        updates.forEach((update) => req.user[update] = req.body[update])
        await req.user.save()
        console.log(updates)
        res.send(req.user)
        res.redirect("/profile");
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

And the AJAX call to the route:

```
(async function editProfile() {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/users/me",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (user) {
            $("#addData")
                .append($("<tr>"))
                .append($("<input>").val(user.name))
                .append($("<tr>"))
                .append($("<input>").val(user.email))
                .append($("<tr>"))
                .append($("<input>").val(user.password))
                ;
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

When i click the update btn i get a page with the unedited json, like this:
[image: json]

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `express-session` which would allow you to give the client a cookie as a key to an object with variables on your server. This way, as they are logged in, you can have access to their `_id` as it occurs in your database, and allow them to edit their specific document.